# Set in Batchable Apex

Tags: apex, batch

How can I use the 'Set' and make the checkbox (Within_Fiscal_Year__c) to 'false' in batchable apex class. I wanted to reset the hours in Contact object to 0 and make the checkbox to false in Training Log object. Please see code below:

I need to get the ContactId from Contact loop and create a set. After that I need to query all training logs using the contactid and the checkbox = true. Once done, I need to update the checkbox to false. Aside from resetting the hours to 0.

```java
global class LRN_ResetSabaHoursBatchable implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            'SELECT Id, SABA_Hours__c, Non_SABA_Hours__c FROM Contact WHERE SABA_Hours__c != NULL'
        );
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Contact> scope){
        List<Contact> contToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
        List<Training_Log__c> trngLogs = [Select Id FROM Training_Log__c WHERE Within_Fiscal_Year__c=True];
        for(Contact contact : scope){                  
            contact.SABA_Hours__c = 0;
            contact.Non_SABA_Hours__c = 0;
            contToUpdate.add(contact);
           }
           update contToUpdate;
        }
        

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        Id job = bc.getJobId();
        system.debug('JOB IS FINISHED');
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of this isn't working? What errors are you receiving? I see nothing in here about a 'Set'. Please edit your question and provide specific information about your problem, steps you've taken to resolve it, and exactly what part of it you're stuck on.

Comment: I need to get the ContactId from Contact loop and create a set. After that I need to query all training logs using the contactid and the checkbox = true. Once done, I need to change the checkbox to false. Aside from resetting the hours to 0.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming you need to update only those contacts which are linked to Training Logs
2. Create a Map of contact Id and Contact records
3. Query all the T Logs which have the flag true and are linked to contacts
4. Update the T Log flag and the corresponding contact's hours
5. Add all necessary null checks and access checks
6. Replace contact_lookup__c  with the correct API name of the contact lookup on T Log object

```java
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Contact> scope) {
    Map<Id, Contact> contactsById = new Map<Id, Contact>(scope);
    List<Training_Log__c> logsToUpdate = new List<Training_Log__c>();
    Map<Id, Contact> contactsToUpdateById = new Map<Id, Contact>();

    for (Training_Log__c log : [SELECT Id, contact_lookup__c FROM Training_Log__c WHERE Within_Fiscal_Year__c = TRUE AND contact_lookup__c IN :contactsById.keySet()]) {
        // update your log records and contact records here
        log.Within_Fiscal_Year__c = false;

        // Logically the contact must always be in the map
        Contact con = contactsById.get(log.contact_lookup__c);

        // However, it may already be being updated
        if (!contactsToUpdateById.containsKey(con.Id)) {
            Contact contactUpdate = new Contact(Id = con.Id,
                    SABA_Hours__c = 0,
                    Non_SABA_Hours__c = 0);

            contactsToUpdateById.put(contactUpdate.Id, contactUpdate);
        }

        logsToUpdate.add(log);
    }

    update logsToUpdate;
    update contactsToUpdateById.values();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tidied up your code a bit. Note that it is not necessary to make batch methods `global`, the use of `new Map<Id, SObject>` is a more efficient way to convert a list of SObjects to a map of SObject by ID and it is best to use a newly created in-memory SObject to give to an update DML to avoid unnecessary writing of other, irrelevant and unchanged fields (which can cause concurrency issues).

Comment: @PhilW Thanks for the update.